# can i transfer the token directly to the publickey?

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account

I save a list of pubkeys I need to transfer tokens to, can I pass it directly in a smart contract or I will have to generate ATA from the client to handle this? thank you.
I try:

```
let transfer_ix = transfer(
        &spl_token::ID,
        &ctx.accounts.owner_address.key(),
        &tx.sender.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.owner_address.key(),
        &[&ctx.accounts.owner_address.key()],
        10,
    )?;
    msg!("transfer_ix: {:?}", transfer_ix);

    invoke(
        &transfer_ix,
        &[ctx.accounts.owner_address.to_account_info()],
    )?;
```

but I got Error: InvalidAccountData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need an ATA. It holds information about the owner, mint, balance or amount, etc. Also, it is mentioned in the Solana docs:

> A user will have at least one token account for every type of token they own.

[see Solana docs](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-create-a-token-account)

Comment: In your smart contract, you can charge a fee from the admin account or let the user pay it when they claim NFTs. For my case when I bulk mint NFTs to reward users I paid ATA and transfer fees from the admin account and later I compensate it form the business logic when the users started doing transactions.